# Prove that country will become self sufficient

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

A country has food deficit of $10\%$. Its population grows continuously at a rate of $3\%$
per year. Its annual food production every year is $4\%$ more than that of the last year. 
Assuming that the average food requirement per person remains constant, prove that the 
country will become self-sufficient in food after n years, where n is the smallest integer 
bigger than 
or equal to    ${\ln 10 - \ln 9} \over {\ln 1.04- 0.03}$

The way I looked at the problem is as such:

$P(t)=$population

$F(t)=$food.

Rate of change of $P(t)$ and $F(t)$ are:

$$\frac {dP(t)} {dt} = k_1P(t)$$
$$\frac {dF(t)} {dt} = k_2F(t)$$ where $k_1=0.03$ and $k_2=0.04$.

The solution of these are:

$$P(t) = P(0)e^{k_1 t}$$
$$F(t) = F(0)e^{k_2 t}$$

I defined the self-sufficiency as $F(t)\over P(t)$. The initial condition is that ${F(0)\over P(0)}=0.9$. If $F(t)\over P(t)$ is greater than or equal to $1$, the country is self-sufficient. Either way, this ought to get you started.

Divide the two equations to get:

$${F(t)\over P(t)} = {F(0)\over P(0)} e^{t(k_2-k_1)}$$ Set $F(t)\over P(t)$ to $1$ and solve for $t$.

$t = 11$ years.

But not got the result . Please help

Comment: You should remove the tags of differential geometry, differential topology, and differential forms. They don't have anything to do with your question.

Comment: Shouldn't that be $P(t)=1.03^t P(0)=P(0)e^{\left({\ln {1.03}}\right)t}$ and $F(t)=1.04^t F(0)=F(0)e^{\left({\ln {1.04}}\right)t}$?

Comment: Well, I suppose "grows continuously at a rate of $3\%$ per year" could mean that it actually compounds continuously, i.e. $P(t)=e^{0.03t}$, but "is $4\%$ more than that of last year" definitely means $F(t)=1.04^t$.

Comment: @GabrielBurns i also have that confusion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have both $F(t)$ and $P(t)$ compounding continuously.  However your problem says that, while the population grows continuously at a $3\%$ rate, food production grows annually by $4\%$.  This is equivalent to continuous growth at a rate of $\ln 1.04$, so your formula for $F(t)$ should be $F(0)e^{\left(\ln 1.04\right)t}$ not $F(0)e^{0.04t}.$  Substituting this into your equation, we get $${F(t) \over P(t)}=0.9e^{\left(\ln 1.04 - 0.03\right)t}$$So we are self-sufficient when $${F(t) \over P(t)}=1=\frac 9 {10} e^{\left(\ln 1.04 - 0.03\right)t}$$ Multiplying both sides by $\frac {10} 9$ gives  $$\frac {10} 9=e^{\left(\ln 1.04-0.03\right)t}$$
Taking the natural log of both sides and solving for $t$ gives the desired result.

Comment: How the continuous growth rate becomes $ln 1.04$

Comment: because the annual rate is $1.04$ (that is, each year, you multiply the previous year's value by $1.04$).  Thus $F(t)=F(0)1.04^t$. But $1.04=e^{\ln 1.04}$, so $1.04^t=\left(e^{\ln 1.04}\right)^t=e^{\left(\ln 1.04\right)t}$.